# Directx Texture interface to existing memory

Tags: memory-management, directx, ipc

I'm writing a rendering app that communicates with an image processor as a sort of virtual camera, and I'm trying to figure out the fastest way to write the texture data from one process to the awaiting image buffer in the other.

Theoretically I think it should be possible with 1 DirectX copy from VRAM directly to the area of memory I want it in, but I can't figure out how to specify a region of memory for a texture to occupy, and thus must perform an additional memcpy.  DX9 or DX11 solutions would be welcome.

So far, the docs here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174363(v=vs.85).aspx have held the most promise.

> "In Windows Vista CreateTexture can create a texture from a system memory pointer allowing the application more flexibility over the use, allocation and deletion of the system memory"

I'm running on Windows 7 with the June 2010 Directx SDK, However, whenever I try and use the function in the way it specifies, I the function fails with an invalid arguments error code.  Here is the call I tried as a test:

```
    static char s_TextureBuffer[640*480*4]; //larger than needed
    void* p = (void*)s_TextureBuffer;
    HRESULT res = g_D3D9Device->CreateTexture(640,480,1,0, D3DFORMAT::D3DFMT_L8, D3DPOOL::D3DPOOL_SYSTEMMEM, &g_ReadTexture, (void**)p);
```

I tried with several different texture formats, but with no luck. I've begun looking into DX11 solutions, it's going slowly since I'm used to DX9. Thanks!